# Schema.org's BreadcrumbList not displaying correctly in Google's search results

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am working on a website where I am implementing Schema.org's `BreadcrumbList`.

The display in Google's search results is not correct. This is how I marked up my breadcrumbs trail:

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
     <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
          <a itemprop="item" href="/"><span itemprop="name">My Website</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
     </li>
     <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
          <a itemprop="item" href="/brands"><span itemprop="name">Brands</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
     </li>
     <li class="active">My Brand</li>
</ol>
```

If I were to Google the name of the brand, then this is how the breadcrumbs trail is displayed in the search results:

```
www.mywebsite.com › ... › Brands › Brands › Brands › Brands
```

Why is there an elipses and why does the word "Brands" display so many times? What do I need to do to fix it?

Is it safe to use `http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList` or should I rather stick to `http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb` for the time being?

Comment: Question about same problem on Webmasters SE: [Breadcrumb bug in Google results, using BreadCrumbList](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/82235/17633)

Comment: Hey Brendan, did you find a solution yet? I have the exact same problem, but even using the data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb is not fixing it.

Comment: This looks like an issue on our (Google's) side -- you shouldn't have to do anything special here.

Comment: @JohnMueller What do I need to do about it? Just leave it and hope that Google fix it within the next couple of days/weeks/months/yars? Or should I implement something other like `http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb`? When will this coming into working?

Comment: @MarkusPint I don't have a solution, it can only be Google that has not implemented the correct way of display it in their search results. So do we wait for them to fix it one day or carry on using something that is prehistoric?

Comment: @BrendanVogt For my site the BreadCrumbList approach started displaying correctly under SERP-s about a week ago. I think Google made some changes just recently.

Comment: @MarkusPint Send me a link to your site please? Are you implementing the newer breadcrumbs or the older version?

Comment: @BrendanVogt https://likvidaator.com The new ones as instructed here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs

Comment: I'm guessing this will be resolved fairly quickly - definitely not a matter of months or years.

Comment: @BrendanVogt I don't see how this can be verified - please provide a link to the page where this happens. I have the schema.org markup working with microdata and breadcrumbs and a number fo others do -  mostly on http://
The ellipsis are because the whole breadcrumb trail is too long, probably because the same Brand is repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does seem to work now. It was probably due to the fact that it was not implemented correctly (from Google's side).

My markup was correct as per specification:

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs